# Does 'separate domain sandboxing' (protecting from JS cookie hijacking) still work with a subdomain?

Tags: javascript, security, cookies

#### A little further detail:

- I'm running a site where users can submit Javascript freely
- Other people will preview this Javascript 'live'
- There will be basic measures in place to stop naughties like `eval()`, but inevitably some may unfortunately slip through
- The site is *mysite.com*, I gather running the scripts from *myotherdomain.com* will prevent cookie hijacking, however will running them from *js.mysite.com* prevent it too? (read: cheapskate, save money on an extra domain)
- Finally, will running it in an `<iframe>` from *mysite.com* to either a separate domain or a subdomain still work as effectively as loading an entirely new site?

Comment: Dude, seriously you will  most likely get the wrong answer from SO for questions like this.  Read the browsersec handbook: http://code.google.com/p/browsersec/

Comment: @The Rook A big thanks for the link to the handbook.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Same Origin Policy(SOP) apply for subdomains, ports, protocols and domain.
If there is a difference in one of these properties the SOP will prevent the access.

As long as you do not use [document.domain](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/document.domain) on your main page, the subdomain will get the SOP protection. If you use `document.domain` in the main page a script could do the same in the `iframe` and by-pass the SOP.

Now if you want to enable some safe communication between iframes, you can use `window.postMessage` if you target modern browsers and mobiles.

And for older browsers there are some tricks to do, like [the window.name trick](http://beebole.com/en/blog/general/sandbox-your-cross-domain-jsonp-to-improve-mashup-security/)

This does not prevent Cross Site Scripting(making a POST to your domain with your current valid cookies from the iframe). You need to use a secret token that only the javascript in your main page knows and that will be sent for each request.

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to run it in an appropriate sandbox, not to strip some code. I think you can do stuff like `delete eval;` or `eval = null;`.  You might have additional luck with `delete document` or `document=null` or `delete document.cookie`. Test on a variety of browsers, of course.

**EDIT:** Also consider using "httponly" cookies, which (on many browsers) prevents them from being accessed in JavaScript. It's originally an IE extension, but has been incorporated to most major browsers IIRC.

Answer (score -1):

Yes a subdomain is the same, except for cookies that are domain cookies.

Comment: Cookies can be read by subdomains, i.e. example.com can be read by foo.example.com. I'm not sure if this is the case if you do not set a domain (I imagine the browser stores the domain for you). To change this, I think you need to use foo.example.com and bar.example.com.